# Entity Framework in an Enterprise Solution

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, wcf-data-services

I pitched my service to our governance board today.  They had some concerns about Entity Framework (especially the head of the data team).

Their were two main concerns:

1. Since EF generates its SQL on the fly is it open to SQL Injection attacks (when used via WCF Services and WCF Data Services).
2. Will EF Scale out to support high load situations without becoming the "slow spot" in the path?

I am fairly sure of #1.  )If EF was open to SQL Injection attacks I think I would have heard about it.)  But I would love something from MS that says the inputs from Data Contracts are [sanitized](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png).  (Kind of like a stored procedure (that does not use Dynamic SQL in the sproc).)

As for #2 I am not sure.  When I start getting high volume of hits against my EF based services, is EF going to cause me grief?

Comment: EF uses **parametrized queries** - so it's definitely **NOT** open to SQL injection! A lot less so than manual SQL code hammered out by so many devs out there.....

Answer (score 4):

1. You're less likely to have SQL injection with EF than with manually-written SQL.
2. There's no simple answer to this. "High load situations" is far too vague to succinctly answer. In general, the bigger you scale, the less *any* "one size fits all" solution works. As always, measure twice, cut once.

Comment: For #1 I was hoping for a bit more.  Maybe the mechanics of how EF does not allow SQL Injection.  For #2, I realize that I was vauge.  But I won't know actual through put until I have done the work to develop my solution with EF.  It is kind of too late at that point to measure if it will be enough.  For an example, suppose I have 200 clients all trying to perform CRUD operations in any given instant (instant, not second).  Each operation would be about 200K in size.  This is a guestimated normal load for my system.  Would EF be able to keep up with that?

Comment: Well, LINQ to Entities uses SQL parameters for any input not defined as constants in code. The only way to have SQL injection with EF are to either use Entity SQL unsafely or to have, e.g., a proc which uses dynamic SQL. Both are much more likely problems in non-EF apps. The limiting factor in your second example could come from EF *or anywhere else.* I believe it could be made to work with EF, but, as with any tool, you may need to learn how to tune it.

Comment: This link may be helpful for performance specifics: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3901.aspx

Comment: And even with Entity SQL, you can't get an SQL injection. Of course your Entity SQL can get injected, so of course you should be careful for any type of injection attack.

Comment: @Craig - That link is for performance on the micro level (an individual query running alone).  I need to know about performance under high load.  Basically the "does it scale well?" question.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Craig. They trust hand-written SQL more than SQL generated by such big tool from Microsoft? To be honest, unless there is a strange bug in EF, it is not possible to do SQL injection, because EF always generates parameterized queries. In other words, their argument is plain bullocks.

And for #2, EF will not be the slow spot, it will always be your database, because you can scale your web service with EF on it out to multiple servers, without much problem most of the time. Scaling out your database however is a completely different ball game. However, I must say that O/RMs can easily generate 'sub optimal' SQL queries that are sometimes hard to tune. DBAs will not always be happy with this. However, in my experience is it is almost always possible to tune those SQL queries (by rewriting the LINQ queries). I've done that a lot in the last few month and it can be quite challenging some times. In that rare case that you can't optimize on the .NET side enough, you can always fall back to an indexed view, stored procedure or manual SQL, but that should be rare.

Comment: re #2 not really ... if EF overhead is 200ms per request you can not scale that overhead out. it will be there if you scale out to 10 servers or 100 servers. For trivial queries (or queries involving complex mappings) EF overhead is often higher than time spent in SQL.

Comment: @Sam: Good point. The delay in time can't be lowered by scaling out. This delay should be small enough for user acceptance.  I've never witnessed a 200ms overhead with EF though.

Comment: I've seen multi-*second* overhead with complicated EF queries. However, I've never seen such overhead which I couldn't fix, nor have I seen a 200ms overhead which I couldn't fix. If EF overhead is higher than SQL for "trivial" queries, then look into `CompiledQuery` or view pregeneration.

Comment: @Craig ... did you see the dapper benchmarks ... compiledquery is pretty nightmarish to use and still much slower than dapper/petapoco. In my blog post: http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/05/02/A+day+in+the+life+of+a+slow+page+at+Stack+Overflow I demonstrated a 78ms delay in l2s, from all my testing it seems that ef is slower than l2s

Comment: @Sam: Your blog post is very informative. You've got yourself a new follower ;-)

Comment: @Sam: Nowhere did I claim that EF is the fastest way to fetch data. Indeed, I'd venture to say that frameworks with zero LINQ support will nearly always be faster than frameworks with LINQ support. Decapitation, after all, cures acne.

Answer (score 3):

Just run the profiler and check what queries EF produces. You will see parametrized queries which are main defence against SQL injection. So no EF is not open to injection attacks but if you are using EntitySQL and concatenating strings manually you can have injection attack on higher layer.

Sure EF has performance costs. This is trade off of easy and rapid development where developers don't need to have too much knowledge about internal processes / technologies to build an application (in case of many MS tools a drilled monkey can build an application but performance and other quality measurements will be adequate).

Actually these performance costs can be very high and it is point of performance testing to find if there is performance bottleneck or not. If you find the part which is too slow it is up to you to optimize it. It can lead to code refactoring or creating stored procedures to handle complex queries.

In  case of DataServices this can be more complex. Client can trigger some complex query which will simply take long and you don't have control over that query. Some defence against this is limiting number of returned / queried records on the service level. If user wants more records he must specify more detailed search criteria.

Comment: WCF Data Services limit records returned by default.

Answer (score 1):

For #2 whenever an abstraction is introduced ther will be a trade-off with performance. Whetther it is significant for you or not can only be determined by performance testing and profiling in your situation. Read this post on why a custom ORM, [Dapper](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/03/30/How+I+learned+to+stop+worrying+and+write+my+own+ORM) was required for SO to give you an idea. Dapper also has a [performance test suite](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/browse/Tests/PerformanceTests.cs) you can use to ascertain how much of an impact EF will have on your typical queries.

There is also a #3. Some features of SQL are still not supported by EF and this could limt your design. e.g. [Unique Key constraints](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/03/09/unique-constraints-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) are not supported yet.

EF is still evolving and keep an eye on the [ADO.Net team blog.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/)

Comment: Unique key constraints *work* fine with the EF. You just have to define them in SSMS, rather than in your model.